# Android ACTION_CALL issue dialing number with DTML codes

Tags: android

I am facing a strange issue when I am trying to dial a number with DTMF using the ACTION_CALL intent. 
Here is the code that I am using to make the call:

```
private void makeCall() {
    try {
        Uri callUri = Uri.parse("tel:08039410333,,,6996833893#,,*1234#,1");
        Log.i("ConferenceManager", callUri.toString());
        Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, callUri);
        startActivity(callIntent);
    } catch(ActivityNotFoundException anf) {
        showToast("Cannot dial specified number");
        anf.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

When I call this method the complete number is not dialed. I can see only "08039410333,,,6996833893" in the Phone application. I am not sure why the complete number is not being sent to the phone application. Please let me know whether there is any other way of sending a large DTMF sequence like the one I am trying.

Comment: Apparently the "#" should be URL encoded ..:( 

    `URLEncoder.encode("#") or append "%23" to send the DTMF pound key`